# Separately sort the digits of each dot-separated number

Tags: shell-script, scripting, ip, sort

I'm trying to sort the numbers of an IP address given from the command line.

Sample inputs and their outputs:

```
Input           - Output
192.168.111.123 - 129.168.111.123
192.312.583.321 - 129.123.358.123
987.654.321.970 - 789.456.123.079
```

Comment: What arguments are you passing to the script? What is your input and what is your expected output?

Comment: The ip address so it would be like ./script.sh 192.312.583 and  192.312.583 would be the argument, the output would be the address in sorted word so 129.123.358

Comment: @Rashad You should edit the question and add what you have written in the last comment. A use example with an input and it's corresponding output helps a lot.

Comment: I believe (suspect / guess) that the OP is trying an artificial exercise in which the “octets” maintain their relative positions, but *the **digits*** in each octet are sorted, e.g., 42.105.83.295 → 24.015.38.259. But, yeah, they need to be clearer, and present any code they’ve tried.

Answer (score 1):

Just putting logic code

```
$ orig_IPADDR="192.168.111.123"
$ sorted_IPADDR=$(echo $orig_IPADDR  | awk -v RS="." -v ORS="." '{cmd="echo "$1"|grep -o .|sort -n| tr -d '\''\n'\''" ; cmd|getline output; close(cmd) ;print output}' | sed 's/.$//')
$ echo $sorted_IPADDR
129.168.111.123
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorting the digits of each dot-separated number:

```bash
$ echo '324.98.120928' | perl -ne 'chomp;for $n (split /\./) { push @s,join("",sort(split //, $n))};print join(".",@s),"\n"'
234.89.012289
```

The Perl script:

```perl
chomp;
for $n ( split /\./ ) {
    push @s, join( "", sort( split //, $n ) );
}
print join( ".", @s ), "\n";
```

This will split up the given string into separate numbers (in `$n`), and then split up each number into separate digits (`split //, $n`).  These digits are then sorted and joined back into numbers before they are pushed onto the array `@s`.

At the end, the array `@s` is printed with dots between the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `sort` command? See `man sort` for all the details, but your question seems like it's calling for a very short, simple and straightforward solution of just piping the list into `sort`.